# Renaming the current process of a ClickOnce application programmatically

Tags: vb.net

I have a ClickOnce application called "Ulti", and I need to run three of this application at once due to my project requirements. During the course of the application, there is a possibility that one or more copies of the application will close due to certain requirements being met.

I have a .bat file scheduled to run every 10 minutes; if not all three copies of the application are running, it should open another instance of the application. However because all three processes of the application are all named "Ulti", my .bat file is unable to differentiate whether or not there are 3 copies of it running, and if not which one is shut down.

As such, is it possible to rename the process of a ClickOnce application dynamically via code at runtime?

Answer (score 0):

You can't rename a process name in runtime. But if your bat file is processes starter you can pass some "Fake" parameter like "1", "2" etc, to your application. It hasn't any effect for your application, but you can differentiate your process by parse command line.

To get process command line parameters you can use **WMIC /?**. Here is an example:

```
@echo off

SET PROCESSNAME=notepad.exe
SET PROCESSDIR=C:\Windows
SET PROCESSFULLPATH=%PROCESSDIR%\%PROCESSNAME%
SET WMIC=C:\Windows\System32\wbem\WMIC.exe

SET PID1=1
SET PID2=2
SET PID3=3

REM Prepare
taskkill /IM notepad.exe
CLS

REM 3 Fake notepads
start /b /d "%PROCESSDIR%" %PROCESSNAME% %PID1%
start /b /d "%PROCESSDIR%" %PROCESSNAME% %PID2%
start /b /d "%PROCESSDIR%" %PROCESSNAME% %PID3%

echo You have a time for manual kill some notepad
pause

REM Restart if not founded 1 or 2 or 3 process.
REM 2nd loop doesn't working

REM Process 1
SET PROCESSID=%PID1%
SET KILLED=1
FOR /F "tokens=2" %%x IN ('%WMIC% /OUTPUT:STDOUT process where Name^="%PROCESSNAME%" get Commandline ^|find "%PROCESSNAME%"') DO (
    IF "%%x"=="%PROCESSID%" (
        SET KILLED=0
    )
)

IF %KILLED%==1 (
    echo Process %PROCESSID% killed. Restarting...

    REM Restart dead copy with %KILLED% index
    start /b /d "%PROCESSDIR%" %PROCESSNAME% %PROCESSID%
)

REM Process 2
SET PROCESSID=%PID2%
SET KILLED=1
FOR /F "tokens=2" %%x IN ('%WMIC% /OUTPUT:STDOUT process where Name^="%PROCESSNAME%" get Commandline ^|find "%PROCESSNAME%"') DO (
    IF "%%x"=="%PROCESSID%" (
        SET KILLED=0
    )
)

IF %KILLED%==1 (
    echo Process %PROCESSID% killed. Restarting...

    REM Restart dead copy with %KILLED% index
    start /b /d "%PROCESSDIR%" %PROCESSNAME% %PROCESSID%
)

REM Process 3
SET PROCESSID=%PID3%
SET KILLED=1
FOR /F "tokens=2" %%x IN ('%WMIC% /OUTPUT:STDOUT process where Name^="%PROCESSNAME%" get Commandline ^|find "%PROCESSNAME%"') DO (
    IF "%%x"=="%PROCESSID%" (
        SET KILLED=0
    )
)

IF %KILLED%==1 (
    echo Process %PROCESSID% killed. Restarting...

    REM Restart dead copy with %KILLED% index
    start /b /d "%PROCESSDIR%" %PROCESSNAME% %PROCESSID%
)
```